# Best source to keep track of US floods?

Tags: usa, weather-and-climate, event-based-effects, texas, natural-disasters

I am currently planning my trip to Texas, where we'll be driving around Houston/Dallas/Austin. Even though we enter Texas Oct 26th, we want to start planning our activities and hotels now.

The recent floods in Texas worry me, especially because they seem to be more frequent. I have been googling a lot on info and have found news of areas flooding close to the areas we want to visit.

I realize there is a big time gap between now and when I want to visit, but I am wondering if there is a way to find out about 'travel advice' in such cases?

How do I know if it's safe to travel?

Is it smart to book now, with this natural disaster occurring? What if my hotel is damaged and not repaired yet when I visit?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call two months a "big time gap".
I mean sure, the waters will have subsided, but that's not long for any repair work.

Comment: @CMaster I guess that only shows how little my knowledge of situations like these is.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this is not something I would worry about.  Hurricanes, tornados, earthquakes, blizzards all just happen and you can't really plan around them.  So...

1. If you are traveling on a common carrier, you can check status before you depart.  Amtrak is showing no delays in the area for example.
2. If and area is genuinely not safe, it would likely either still be restricted, such as residents only, or closed, such as a damaged bridge.
3. Yes, the best discounts are typically available further out from your travel dates.
4. Then you can't stay there :).  If floods are the concern, the availability of you hotel can be know well in advance.  Just call and ask if they're open.

If you are really worried, you can always get Travel Insurance.